# Finding value in array .inArray()

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm using `.inArray()` to check my array for a '0' value and then `return false;` or break the function if there is a zero.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calc').click(function(e) {

        var drop = $(".drop"),
            c = [],
            g = [];

        //Push values into an array.
        drop.each(function() {
            var $t = $(this),
                cals = $t.val(),
                option = $(':selected', this),
                gly = parseFloat(option.attr('rel'));
            g.push(gly * 2);
            c.push(cals * 2);
        });

        var inthere = jQuery.inArray('0', c) > -1;

        //don't calculate if array is empty
        if (c.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        //don't calculate with a '0' value in array
        if (inthere == true) {
            return false;
        }

        //shouldn't display if you haven't added a dropdown OR if the dropdown stayed on the "Default" option
        alert('Passed');
    });

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('#contain').append('<select class="drop"><option value="" rel="" data-default="true">Default</option><option value="1" rel="2">Option 1</option><option value="3" rel="4">Option 2</option></select>');
    });

});​
```

When the user leaves the `option` at the "Default" option, the value passed to `c` should be 0. For some reason, the code will pass, unless I haven't added in a dropdown...

How can I prevent the code from continuing if there is a '0' in the `c` array???

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdunham02/DUs8e/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array doesn't have a string matching `'0'`, it has a number matching `0`.

http://jsfiddle.net/DUs8e/1/

```
var inthere = jQuery.inArray(0, c) > -1;
```

Comment: I figured this out 3 seconds before you posted it! haha, I was going to ask why, but you answered that also, thank you!